# How do routers route packets to very far destinations they've never made contact with?

Tags: networking, routes

I've taken a few networking classes in school and I remember how a router will build a routing table of nearby routers/routers its interacted with.

My question is that surely there a large number of times where my router in the US will have no idea about a router in a far flung corner of the globe. Or if a router just gets turned on,  it won't be known to many more places than its local neighborhood.

So what happens to packets that are routed to some far place? How does my local home router know how to get it to this place? Is there a next hop that if a router doesn't know where to send it just passes it up to a router with possibly a larger routing table (ISP or something similar)?

Thanks!

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Default_route

Comment: "_How do routers route packets to very far destinations they've never made contact with?_" They do not. Routers route packets between networks by sending a packet to the next router interface toward the destination. If the routing table does not have a matching destination the router drops the packet. The Internet routing table is huge. You home router simply has a destination to `0.0.0.0/0`, which matches every IPv4 address, pointing to the ISP router.

Comment: "Network Engineering" would be a better community for this question; it is not a programming question.

Answer (score 0):

The big folks : [Autonomous Systems](https://www.cidr-report.org/as2.0/) interconnect via BGP, the little ones (including your home router) uses next-hop default route.

Typically DHCP provides your computer/router/laptop/cellphone with a minimum:

- IP Address / Subnet Mask / Gateway.

Which is enough to get the other side of the planet.

The Gateway is the next-hop / default route.

Phone (gateway: via dhcp) >> Wifi (gateway: via dhcp) >> Cable Modem (gateway: via dhcp) >> ISP (various igp, finally bgp) >> Other AS (World)

Answer (score 0):

Routing protocols are used to distributed information about the location of each IP address.

Some routing protocols (e.g. RIP, OSPF, ISIS) are limited in geographical scope, i.e. they cover a single organization. These are called intra-domain routing protocols.

Other routing protocols (e.g. BGP) are global in scope, i.e. they cover the entire world. These are called inter-domain routing protocols.

Either way, routing protocols don't distribute information about each individual IP address in the world. If they did, they would have to distribute information about billions of IP addresses which is not feasible.

Instead, routers do something that is called "aggregation". They advertise only summary routes (which are called "aggregates") for large groups of IP addresses.

For example, BGP might advertise a single route for 180.24.0.0/16 which is aggregate for all IP addresses whose first 16 bits are 180.24 and whose last 16 bits can be anything.

For example, a router in Boston (USA) might only have a single aggregate route for all destinations in France. Once the packet arrives in France (say in Paris), the French routers will have "more specific" routes to destinations within France.

A default route (0.0.0.0/0) is simply the most extreme case of aggregation: it is a single route that covers all destinations in the entire world.

When you connect your laptop to your Wifi router, your laptop installs a single default route (0.0.0.0/0) pointing to your Wifi router.

In essence, no matter what the final destination on the Internet is, the first hop from your laptop is always to the Wifi router.